# What is the most efficient method to write a multiple choices story?

Tags: storyboard

I’d like to tell a story through a video game, and I’m starting to write it. But I got like 8 characters, some of them dies, some don’t, player has important choices changing the way characters talk to him or interact to eachother and I’m looking for an efficient way to get the story on paper before starting to code.

Do you guys know a clever way to write this ? I tried to make a file for each path, but its a bit messy

Comment: I'd suggest googling the tree data structure. You might find a variant useful to your purposes. In fact, I would suggest giving each branch a reference to a function that checks a global condition. Then, moving down that branch will progress the game in some fundamental manner.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at some established interactive fiction developers who have published their process — for instance, [Inkle, developers of 80 Days, have given several excellent GDC talks about their approach to writing interactive scripts](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1021774/Adventures-in-Text-Innovating-in) and even [shared some of their tools](http://www.inklestudios.com/inklewriter/). You'll find many other interactive fiction developers sharing similarly, so it's well worth hearing from several of them to compare approaches.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you have a very branching story, it can be helpful to keep track of the main story outline in form of a flowchart. [Here is one for the visual novel Katawa Shoujo](http://bildr.no/image/1357233.jpeg) (posting it inline would be quite pointless due to the huge size of the image). This image was created by fans after the game was published. It is not the one they used during development. But it still gives a good impression how such a flowchart could look.

There are lots of programs to create charts like that. I would use Microsoft Visio, but there are lots of alternatives available which don't cost nearly as much.

Behind each of these boxes is a dialog scene which you would have to write down separately. When you have an author-friendly toolchain, it might make sense to write them directly in the format in which your game engine can read it. That way you can test them immediately. A short test-cycle is just as important for the story as it is for the gameplay. Dialog lines often read differently in the context of your game than when you read them in a text editor. If you don't have an author-friendly toolchain, invest the time into building one. That investment will amortize itself quickly.

The nice thing about such a chart is that you can use it as a kind of todo-list which you can print out and put checkmarks on after you wrote, proofread and testplayed a scene.

Comment: If you want to make a flowchart, I recommend the free program CmapTools

Comment: A mind mapping tool is a similar option that may fit well for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with it myself, but I've been pointed to [Twine](https://twinery.org/) for something like that. It is an editor and a story player, but there should be plenty of export function to get it in the game editor of your choice when you are done.

Comment: Yes, Twine editor indeed has nice flowcharts in the editor.

Answer (score -1):

There is mathematical formalism to make sure you get branching story where events can happen in various orders. It is called [Petri Nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net). There is nice [write-up](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~riedl/pubs/aiide11.pdf). You can either use [Petri Net editor](http://doku.telematik.uni-freiburg.de/wolfgang) or [MUSE storytelling engine](https://musestorytelling.org).

This should greatly simplify your task!

Why?
Because it is rather time consuming to get all possible playthrough through exhaustive testing. It is preferred to find a way to automatically map and test your story.

One way to quickly playtest a story, is to just write it as interactive fiction in InkleStudios Ink, and then improve.

However automatic testing will decrease the time that humans need to spend on the task.

Comment: You seem to be saying "this is", but offer no reason why. Perhaps those answers are provided through the links, but we tend to not judge an answer by the links. Perhaps you could provide more useful information, here in the answer?